# Change Spaces (%20) to -

Tags: php

Hey I have my website URL linking to here at the moment:

```
 <div id="blog_posts_container">
    <h3><a href="<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['post_id']) ? $row_getDisplay['post_id'] : ''); ?>_<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['title']) ? $row_getDisplay['title'] : ''); ?>.html"<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['title']) ? $row_getDisplay['title'] : ''); ?></a></h3>
```

and in my .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*).html$ post.php?post_id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

How would I get my URLS from "86_I%20am,%20who%20I%20am.html" to "86_I-am-who-I-am.html"

EDIT:
I did it and I got it to replace special characters such as : ; / etc but now it has the spaces again. Here is my code:

```
<h3><a href="<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['post_id']) ? $row_getDisplay['post_id'] : ''); ?>_<?php echo str_replace(array(':', '\\', '/', '*'), ' ', urldecode($row_getDisplay['title'])); ?>.html" ><?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['title']) ? $row_getDisplay['title'] : ''); ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: Why do you get such a weird urls at first place? How about generating good urls originally, not trying to fix garbage?

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_replace` function replace space to - like this:

$url = str_replace(' ', '-', urldecode($row_getDisplay['title']));

see PHP manual [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: You need to do urldecode($row_getDisplay['title']) so your solution works properly.

Comment: @m4t1t0 Sorry my english is not good, i didn't understand, please help me modify it, thank you :)

Comment: @Robdogga55 before output replace title

Comment: Thanks I got it too. One more thing, how would I remove all special characters in a URL (such as ! : etc..)

Comment: @Robdogga55 `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )` $search, $replace parameters support use array.  you know what I mean

Comment: @likai I have it replacing special characters but now there are all spaces. I have edited it original post with it now..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23398/discussion-between-robdogga55-and-likai)

Answer (score 0):

```
 urldecode($row_getDisplay['title'])
```

%20 is space between words